# Difference between $\models$ and $\Rightarrow$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

What is the difference between $\models$ and $\Rightarrow$ in propositional logic?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by $\Rightarrow$. Some authors essentially take it to mean $\models$, others take it to mean material implication. Can you say which particular book you are using?

Comment: Dont know if it helps, I am reading "Modeling and reasoning with bayesian networks". I have always believed they were the same, but I am beginning to think that the author does not. What is the potential difference?

Answer (score 7):

In the book "Modeling and reasoning with Bayesian networks", page 14, $\Rightarrow$ is defined to be the material implication connective. Some other authors write this as $\rightarrow$.

Other authors write $\Rightarrow$ as a synonym for $\models$, which is a connective in the metatheory that indicates logical implication.

Both conventions appear often enough that you have to look at each author's conventions individually.

Comment: @user1090614: I agree with Carl, although I've often seen $\models$ be used for *semantic entailment*, i.e., $(A\models B)\Rightarrow$ "*A and B mean the same thing*" while the $\Rightarrow$ has been used in the sense of *formally implies*.

Comment: A connective connects similar kinds of objects.  $\models$ doesn't do this, and consequently is not a connective.

Comment: @Doug Spoonwood: it is common in the metatheory to write $\phi \models \psi$, where $\phi$ and $\psi$ are both formulas of the same logic. In that case $\models$ looks like a connective to me.

Comment: @CarlMummert In that case I agree once we have parentheses expressed.  However, it is also common enough to write things like (p⇒q), (q⇒r) $\models$ (p⇒r), where the left hand side gets understood as a *set* of propositions.  A set of propositions is not the same sort of object as a proposition.  So, in that case it doesn't look like a connective to me.

Comment: @Doug Spoonwood: so the next step is to ask: what exactly *are* the formal expressions of the metatheory.

Comment: @CarlMummert I don't recall seeing formal expressions of the metatheory.  I'm not sure that they make any sense.

Comment: @Eupraxis1981 That $A$ semantically entails $B$ (written $A \models B$) doesn't mean that $A$ and $B$ mean the same thing.  It means that any model of $A$ must also be a model of $B$.  It _doesn't_ mean that any model of $B$ must also be a model of $A$.

Comment: $\models$ gets used in a number of ways.  We may write: $\phi\models\psi$ with formulae; $\Phi\models\psi$ with a set of formulae and a formula; ${\cal M}\models\phi$ with a semantic model (whatever that might be in context) and a formula.  I think that the last the most general, since the others can be expressed in terms of it.  E.g., $\Phi\models\psi$ means that each ${\cal M}$ such that ${\cal M}\models\phi$ for every $\phi\in\Phi$ is such that ${\cal M}\models\psi$.  $\phi\models\psi$ means $\{\phi\}\models\psi$.

Answer (score 3):

⇒ is a logical connective in the object language.  It connects two propositions.  It has a specific truth table and/or a characterization by a set of axioms (or axiom schema) under a rule of inference(s).

$\models$ happens in the metalanguage and usually refers only to semantic entailment.  It doesn't connect individual propositions, but rather relates a proposition or a set of propositions to another proposition or set of propositions.  It doesn't have a truth table.  With $\models$ we can write things likes

$\models$ (p⇒q).

p $\models$ q.

{p, q, r} $\models$ (p⇒(q⇒r)).

There is no meaningful statement like {p, q, r} ⇒ (p⇒(q⇒r)), because ⇒ only relates particular propositions, not sets of propositions.